# Why can we not nominate others?

Tags: discussion, election

Why can we only nominate ourselves and not others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see

http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/what-is-the-reason-for-insisting-on-self-nomination/1305#1305

Comment: Odd, it seems to have worked on MO.

Comment: @th. every time we have tried it, it has led to anger and heartache. Simpler for everyone involved to not allow it. If you want to run, run. Easy.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to ask for "volunteers", then, rather than "nominations"?

Comment: @samb no, it would not http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75438/change-nominate-to-volunteer/75450#75450